# Confused in getting nested elements and values via XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, nested, xmldocument

I am trying to access quite a deep XML file, yet I get confused and just brute forced access to an element to get the elements within it, My problem is, it does not work (`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`) and my method of getting the "dictory" of the XML looks very inefficient,

My goal is to grab all the `<ramStick>` via a foreach loop since it can have 1-* ramSticks

Here is part of my C# code that I am having an issue with:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string xmlFilePath = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\userInfo.xml";
        doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

        XmlNodeList accountList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("account");

        foreach (XmlNode node in accountList)
        {
            XmlElement accountElement = (XmlElement)node;
            // I got inside this loop at this point and can get an accountElement with values

            String hostname = accountElement.GetElementsByTagName("user")[0].InnerText;

            // This is where I get confused and don't know what I am really doing and I just experiment
            XmlNode accountRoot = accountElement.GetElementsByTagName("systemInfo")[0];

            XmlElement ramNode = (XmlElement)accountRoot;
            XmlNode ramInfo = ramNode.GetElementsByTagName("ramInfo")[0];
            XmlElement ramList = (XmlElement)ramInfo;
            XmlNodeList ramStick = ramList.GetElementsByTagName("ramStick");

            // I want to run a foreach loop on each ramStick to get the values
            foreach (XmlNode ramNodeForLoop in ramStick)
            {
                XmlElement ramData = (XmlElement)ramNodeForLoop;

                String partNumber = ramData.GetElementsByTagName("partNumber")[0].InnerText;
            }

        }`
```

I have quite a big XML file which contains multiple `<account>` here is a sample of it:

```
<account>
        <user>OYSTER-PC</user>
        <systemInfo>
            <dskInfo>
                <dskInterface>
                            <deviceID>C:</deviceID><description>Local Fixed Disk</description><size>500000878592</size><freeSpace>377396776960</freeSpace><fileSystem>NTFS</fileSystem><volumeSerialNumber>4C922158</volumeSerialNumber>
                </dskInterface>
                <dskInterface>
                            <deviceID>D:</deviceID><description>CD-ROM Disc</description><size/><freeSpace/><fileSystem/><volumeSerialNumber/>
                </dskInterface>
                <dskInterface>
                            <deviceID>E:</deviceID><description>CD-ROM Disc</description><size/><freeSpace/><fileSystem/><volumeSerialNumber/>
                </dskInterface>
            </dskInfo>
            <hddInfo>
                <hddInterface>
                            <model>ST9500325AS ATA Device</model><interfaceType>IDE</interfaceType><name>\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0</name><partitions>1</partitions><serialNumber>2020202020202020202020205636384547535146</serialNumber><status>OK</status>
                </hddInterface>
            </hddInfo>
            <nicInfo>
                <nicInterface>
                            <macAddress>48:5D:60:03:88:04</macAddress><description>Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter</description><ipAddress>192.168.1.10</ipAddress><ipSubnet>255.255.255.0</ipSubnet><defaultIpGateway>192.168.1.1</defaultIpGateway><dhcpServer>192.168.1.1</dhcpServer>
                </nicInterface>
                <nicInterface>
                            <macAddress>74:F0:6D:A8:4E:32</macAddress><description>Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)</description><ipAddress/><ipSubnet/><defaultIpGateway/><dhcpServer/></nicInterface>
                <nicInterface>
                            <macAddress>20:41:53:59:4E:FF</macAddress><description>RAS Async Adapter</description><ipAddress/><ipSubnet/><defaultIpGateway/><dhcpServer/>
                </nicInterface>
                <nicInterface>
                            <macAddress>20:CF:30:55:0C:EF</macAddress><description>JMicron PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Adapter</description><ipAddress/><ipSubnet/><defaultIpGateway/><dhcpServer/>
                </nicInterface>
            </nicInfo>
            <ramInfo>
                <ramStick>
                            <partNumber>M471B5273DH0-CK0  </partNumber><serialNumber>E2CE33AF</serialNumber><capacity>4294967296</capacity>
                </ramStick>
                <ramStick>
                            <partNumber>M471B5273DH0-CK0  </partNumber><serialNumber>630155D0</serialNumber><capacity>4294967296</capacity>
                </ramStick>
            </ramInfo>
        </systemInfo>
    </account>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xpath like this:

```
foreach (XmlElement element in doc.SelectNodes("//account/systemInfo/ramInfo/ramStick"))
{
    string partNumber = element["partNumber"].InnerText;
}
```

Note that since this call to SelectNodes returns only XmlElement, I can use XmlElement as type for the loop variable. Otherwise I'd have to use XmlNode.

Comment: I tried this code, but It didn't enter the loop at all
(debugged by adding a writeline inside the loop), it didn't print so I couldn't enter, I am sure I have a value for every ramStick within the XML file

Thanks for the response by the way =)

Comment: I copy-pasted the XML into LinqPad, ran the code and got M471B5273DH0-CK0, M471B5273DH0-CK0. Did you include the correct XML?

Comment: Yes I did get the correct XML source since I was able to display the hostname and other info (that i didn't include here) in the first loop, (have 5 accounts with complete info in my XML)

Comment: I changed the code from "/account" to "//account" which will match account regardless of its position in the file. You mention you have multiple account elements in the file, but do not mention what the top level element name is.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that, I made it work but it prints all values when I use the complete "directory" of elements or the "//account" as you said.

Though I can do a workaround for this, is there a way to print the ones that are of the current "<account>" within the foreach loop for future coding purposes =)

Thanks for all the help man

Comment: If "node" points to a account, you can use node.SelectNodes("systemInfo/ramInfo/ramStick"). Basic xpath is very useful to know: you can think of the XML as a file system where "C:" is your root element, and the xpath as a file/directory path.

Comment: That worked x.x i kept adding a slash before system info that's why it didn't work, thanks man =)

Answer (score 0):

After recoding so much,

Here is what I finally did...

```
            XmlNode systemInfo = node.SelectSingleNode("systemInfo");
            XmlNode ramInfo = systemInfo.SelectSingleNode("ramInfo");
            XmlNodeList ramList = ramInfo.SelectNodes("ramStick");

            foreach (XmlElement ramStick in ramList)
            {
                    // add code here
            }
```